# Can older iPhones (with iOS 11) display HEIF images?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, heif

Consider the scenario of restoring a backup taken on an HEIF/HEVC capable device (e.g. the iPhone 7 or newer) to an older device (e.g. an iPhone 6s, running iOS 11).

Will images and videos taken on the new device and accessed on the old one be:

- Not restored at all?
- Restored, but not displayable (i.e. taking up space, accessible for sharing/uploading etc., but not shown in the gallery)?
- Be fully compatible, and displayed/decoded in software?

Is there a difference between images and videos? (I could imagine that images are decoded in software on older devices, for example.)

Comment: I can answer your question in the title for HEIF/HEVC, but I can't say for sure what will happen when you restore.

Answer (score 2):

There wouldn't be a problem with that. The older iPhone would be able to convert the image back to a readable format.

More info [here](https://www.macworld.com/article/3226490/ios/ios-11-hevc-heif-and-what-you-need-to-know-about-these-new-video-and-photo-formats.html).

Edit: This will be an issue if trying to view the videos on a mid-2014 MacBook Pro or older. There is ways around it, but only the 2015+ editions can automatically convert them.
I have recently found this out while trying to view videos from my iPhone 8 on my mid-2014 MBP.